# IE 8 cannot find CSS file on selection change

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an asp form on my page. The form elements are styled by a css file called product.css
The form has 3 select boxes. As I load the page, the CSS loads just fine and everything displays alright. 
As soon as I select a value in the select boxes, the callback leads to a point where the product.css file is nowhere to be found by IE. this is only happening in IE 7/8. Rest all the browsers including IE9 are working fine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: We're going to need to see some code. What does the callback do?

Comment: Please paste your code so I can see and help you in this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here an encoder decoder in asp. Hope that helps you

```
Function Base64Encode(inData)
'rfc1521
'2001 Antonin Foller, Motobit Software, http://Motobit.cz

Const Base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
Dim cOut, sOut, I

'For each group of 3 bytes

For I = 1 To Len(inData) Step 3
Dim nGroup, pOut, sGroup

'Create one long from this 3 bytes.

nGroup = &H10000 * Asc(Mid(inData, I, 1)) + _
&H100 * MyASC(Mid(inData, I + 1, 1)) + MyASC(Mid(inData, I + 2, 1))

'Oct splits the long To 8 groups with 3 bits

nGroup = Oct(nGroup)

'Add leading zeros

nGroup = String(8 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup

'Convert To base64

pOut = Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)) + 1, 1) + _
Mid(Base64, CLng("&o" & Mid(nGroup, 7, 2)) + 1, 1)

'Add the part To OutPut string

sOut = sOut + pOut

'Add a new line For Each 76 chars In dest (76*3/4 = 57)
'If (I + 2) Mod 57 = 0 Then sOut = sOut + vbCrLf

Next
Select Case Len(inData) Mod 3
Case 1: '8 bit final

sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 2) + "=="
Case 2: '16 bit final

sOut = Left(sOut, Len(sOut) - 1) + "="
End Select
Base64Encode = sOut
End Function

Function MyASC(OneChar)
If OneChar = "" Then MyASC = 0 Else MyASC = Asc(OneChar)
End Function



Function Base64Decode(ByVal base64String)
'rfc1521
'1999 Antonin Foller, Motobit Software, http://Motobit.cz

Const Base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
Dim dataLength, sOut, groupBegin

'remove white spaces, If any

base64String = Replace(base64String, vbCrLf, "")
base64String = Replace(base64String, vbTab, "")
base64String = Replace(base64String, " ", "")

'The source must consists from groups with Len of 4 chars

dataLength = Len(base64String)
If dataLength Mod 4 <> 0 Then
Err.Raise 1, "Base64Decode", "Bad Base64 string."
Exit Function
End If


' Now decode each group:

For groupBegin = 1 To dataLength Step 4
Dim numDataBytes, CharCounter, thisChar, thisData, nGroup, pOut
' Each data group encodes up To 3 actual bytes.

numDataBytes = 3
nGroup = 0

For CharCounter = 0 To 3
' Convert each character into 6 bits of data, And add it To
' an integer For temporary storage. If a character is a '=', there
' is one fewer data byte. (There can only be a maximum of 2 '=' In
' the whole string.)

thisChar = Mid(base64String, groupBegin + CharCounter, 1)

If thisChar = "=" Then
numDataBytes = numDataBytes - 1
thisData = 0
Else
thisData = InStr(1, Base64, thisChar, vbBinaryCompare) - 1
End If
If thisData = -1 Then
Err.Raise 2, "Base64Decode", "Bad character In Base64 string."
Exit Function
End If

nGroup = 64 * nGroup + thisData
Next

'Hex splits the long To 6 groups with 4 bits

nGroup = Hex(nGroup)

'Add leading zeros

nGroup = String(6 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup

'Convert the 3 byte hex integer (6 chars) To 3 characters

pOut = Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2))) + _
Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2))) + _
Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)))

'add numDataBytes characters To out string

sOut = sOut & Left(pOut, numDataBytes)
Next

Base64Decode = sOut
End Function
```